Getting exception Shared access keyt cant be empty with CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider
Getting the below transient error when use CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider
TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();
client = new QueueClient(this.config.ServiceBusEndpoint, queueName, tokenProvider, TransportType.Amqp, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
Stacktrace:   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Primitives.SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider..ctor(String keyName, String sharedAccessKey, Func`2 customKeyEncoder, TimeSpan tokenTimeToLive, TokenScope tokenScope)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Primitives.SharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider..ctor(String keyName, String sharedAccessKey, TokenScope tokenScope)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection.InitializeConnection(ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection..ctor(String namespaceConnectionString, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection..ctor(String namespaceConnectionString)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient..ctor(String connectionString, String entityPath, ReceiveMode receiveMode, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
at
Added retry mechanism but still didnt work
